# How to update textviews when seekbar is dragged

Tags: java, android, listener, runnable, android-seekbar

Here you can see what im trying to achieve

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIUD.jpg

The first gif is what i have now, and the second on is what i want to get.

The code works but the textview which displays song current position is only updating when i stop dragging, but i want it to update when im dragging it.

Check out the gifs i posted in the link so you understand what i want to achieve.

Thanks in advance,

Vince

updateProgressBar(); called when i change a song

**My code**

```
private Runnable mUpdateTime = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    long songCurrentTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    long songTotalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();

    tvSongCurrentTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songCurrentTime));
    tvSongTotalTime.setText(""+utilities.msToTimer(songTotalTime));

    int progress = (int)(utilities.getProgressPercentage(songCurrentTime, songTotalTime));
    seekBar.setProgress(progress);

    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
}
};

  public void updateProgressBar(){
     mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 100);
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
fromUser) {

} 

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTime);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTime);
    int songTotalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration() ;
    int currentPosition = utilities.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), 
    songTotalTime);

    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

Comment: use updateProgressBar(); in onProgressChanged also

Comment: https://github.com/naman14/Timber check this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in 'onProgressChanged' method. Like this :

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
    fromUser) {
    if(fromUser)
        //myTextView.setText("" + progress);
        updateProgressBar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below code. It may help you.

```
final TextView sometextview=findViewById(R.id.someid);//your textview
sometextview.setText("Hello Android");        

        final SeekBar seekbar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.someseekbar);   //your seekbar  
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() { //listener for your seekbar      

        @Override       
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }       

        @Override       
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        }       

        @Override       
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {     
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

            sometextview.setTextSize(progress+"%");//Here is the textview with the progress number.

        }       
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply You are code in your project is wrong method, see below cut and paste the code in right method ...do code in `onProgressChanged`  method

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
fromUser) {

int songTotalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration() ;
    int currentPosition = utilities.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), 
    songTotalTime);

    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
    updateProgressBar();

} 

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTime);
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTime);

}
```